# Set backup date format for Ansible template module

Tags: ansible

How do you change the date format for files that Ansible's template module creates when you use the `backup` option?

For example, the command:

`template: src=supervisord.conf.j2 dest=/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf backup=yes`

creates a backup file: `supervisord.conf.2015-08-24@12:17~`

I'd like it to be something like: `supervisord.conf.20150824_1217`

Comment: I guess you can't since there is no option. It's either _on_ or _off_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot change it.  It's hardcoded in [lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/b377301195e7d7720551538a33d2499eee1a1d30/lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py#L1320) and unconfigurable.